# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:Algorithm PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 not available

Tags: security

My webserver, orion 1.5.4, run on jre 1.4.2, when I run

> SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

the following exception is thrown

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:Algorithm PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 not available

I google and find need to add Bouncy Castle provider, so I download bcprov-jdk14-150.jar and placed it in classpath, and download the unlimited policy files in the JVM, then when I run the program code, error thrown in line

> aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(ivByte));

the error message is

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs
>       at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.(DashoA12275)
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted signers!
>       at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA12275)
>       at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.g(DashoA12275)
>       at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.f(DashoA12275)
>       at javax.crypto.SunJCE_t.run(DashoA12275)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       ... 16 more

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I download the unlimited policy files for java 1.6 wrongly, should download for java 1.4.

thanks